# Php Myadmin not able to access the Database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

All of a sudden my phpMyadmin has stopped working and I am getting following error .

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 

 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

The error Log is showing following message :

```
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-09-23 18:31:46 2764 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 279580685 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-09-23 18:31:46 10080 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
```

Any Idea how I can fix this error .

Or is there any other way I can acess the Mysql installed in Xampp

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

From the error report looks like the server did crash and corrupted some of the data. Try following the steps below, from top to bottom.

There are severals problems that may give a "Connection Refused" error (the one you got).

The first thing you should check is OS integrity.The error log should a problem there. If you are sure your OS is fine, then proceed below.

If you are trying to connect locally (using a local IP), the problem may be given due to the fact that `bind-address` is set (or not commented) as well as the `skip-networking` not commented in the my.cnf file.
Check your my.cnf file for those lines.

---

Another possible issue is that your user is not allowed to connect.
If you access to the mysql console, try to check user data and permissions, and/or eventually create a new user.
The query to view all users is `SELECT Host, user FROM mysql.user;`.
This will show you all users, as well as the IP they can connect from.
The wildcard for "any IP" is %. If you see your username with a % as host, it means you are allowed to connect.

To create a new user, and grant him all permissions, you need to run 2 query.
First, create the user with: `ADD USER "user"@"IP" IDENTIFIED BY "password";`

Once you have done that, run a `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO "user"@"IP";`. That will make sure your new user has access to everything in the database server.

---

If you are trying to connect remotely, in addition to checking the things needed for a locan connection, check your router's port forwarding. MySQL uses port 3306 (by default). Make sure the port is open, else the router will refuse the connection.

If the problem persists after you have the correct user and IP, port is open and the server is not bount to a specific address, you should be able to connect correctly.

If, after all the above has been done, you still aren't able to connect to your mysql server, then there is probably something else hindering your connection. Check the host you are using to connect, and eventually any element in the connection.

---

You can check the connection the server itself using a Telnet. Just type in `o "remote-ip" 3306` to see if you can succesfully connect to the server. The connection will probably be closed right after. The important thing is that it does start.

---

Sorry for such a huge answer. Hope it will solve your problem